# Flutter - Bypass Silent and Dot Not Disturb Mode on iOS and Android?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this app where it receives notifications from Firebase using firebase messaging.  The notifications are very important and needed to be sound even if the phone is on silent or do not disturb mode.  I searched through pub but cannot find any packages that will achieve it.  I think I can use Flutter's android alarm manager to achieve this on Android but will I be able to do it on the iOS without writing native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: You can't.

Long Answer: You can, but only if the user allows the app to bypass Do Not Disturb, which they can only do if their Android version supports it. With regards to silent mode, you're out of luck. I guess you could try using an Alarm, but I wouldn't recommend misusing it like that. With regards to iOS, I don't know for sure, but I think it's even more locked down than Android, so you're probably out of luck there.