# How to prevent interruptions when recording video with Flutter?(notifications, calls, low power)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to prevent users to get interrupted when they are recording their workout.

I find a way with power plugin to manage power notifications but is there any other way to prevent user to get interrupted by notifications, calls when they are recording video?

Also I look for a way to start do not disturb but so far I only find solution for android.|

related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58176473/9779791